# Embedding documents in web maps?

Tags: arcgis-online, attachments

The county I work for currently has an ArcGIS online web map on their public works website that shows our capital improvement projects as polygons with a PDF linked in the popup showing project info and updates: http://www.yorkcounty.gov/380/Public-Works
Right now every time there is an update, we find the project in an Excel spreadsheet, save the sheet as a PDF, and swap out the old PDF attachment for the new one in the ArcGIS online layer. This has become labor intensive so we are looking for a way to streamline this processes into as few steps as possible.

What we are looking for is a way to automatically add updates to a project document and have them linked to their respective projects in the map?

Comment: Are you currently storing the PDFs on your ArcGIS institutional account?

Comment: We have a layer in AGOL specifically for attaching the PDF to the polygon in the web map. Every time there is an update we swap out the PDF for the project in question with an updated version.